# Map the versioned [automapper-x] tags to [automapper]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Just by looking at the number of questions about [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) we can say that it is somewhat popular. I'm asking for community consensus whether we should set up tag synonyms from the versioned tags to the main automapper tag.

My proposal technically is to map:

[automapper-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automapper-2), [automapper-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automapper-3), [automapper-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automapper-4), [automapper-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automapper-5) to [automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automapper).

<sub>* Added image below with proper red freehand circle indicator for better readability</sub>
[image]

My current tag score doesn't let me to send in tag synonym suggestions since I would need 5 points for that. And after having a chat with Bhargav Rao about this, he told me the way it's used to handle cases like this is to ask on Meta.

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted that tag synonyms effectively destroy the usefulness of version-specific tags. Can you make an argument that there is no need for version-specific tags, that all AutoMapper questions should simply be tagged [tag:automapper]? Are there no salient version-specific differences?

Comment: @CodyGray personally I'm not aware of major breaking changes between versions (I'm using this lib. on say a weekly basis at work...), if so the official [documentation](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/07/07/automapper-5-0-released/) has a link for about "breaking changes" covered [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide). So it's really up to the community to decide.